# WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity : Devise with OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise, omniauth, helper

Suddenly I started getting this error while submitting a form. The only change I made is calling a method defined in ApplicationController which is marked as helper.

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :is_org_admin?

  #Check if current user is Admin in current organization or not
  def is_org_admin?
    session[:current_organization].is_admin?(current_user)
  end
end
```

is_admin? is defined as

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  def is_admin?(user)
    member = memberships.where(user_id: user.id).first
    if member.nil?
      false
    else
      member.is_admin?
    end
  end
end
```

And is_org_admin? method is being called from view template

**app/views/users/index.html.haml**

```
 %h1 Users
    - if is_org_admin?
      %p= link_to 'Invite new user', new_invitation_path
```

If I remove `protect_from_forgery` in ApplicationController or call to helper method `if is_org_admin?` in index.html.haml it works. But as I enable `protect_from_forgery` or the condition which calls helper defined in ApplicationController, it gives the warning and shows **You need to sign in or sign up before continuing** message on the page.

Would anyone please suggest what is the problem here?

Comment: If I replace `session[:current_organization].is_admin?(current_user)` with `Organization.find(session[:current_organization].id).is_admin?(current_user)` it works.

Comment: I saved current organization model in session which is bad idea as per http://railscasts.com/episodes/13-dangers-of-model-in-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving entire Organization model, I am saving it's id in session to have instance of current organization. So as required, I search it on the fly.

```
Organization.find(session[:current_organization_id]).is_admin?(current_user)
```

Still I wonder why it returns 401 if organization AR saved and used from session.